# How can I apply a firewall rule to a specific local IP?

Tags: iptables, ipv4

I host gameservers and as a result have a few IPs.
On the main server IP I have the game panel, other IPs are reserved for use by the gameservers I host for my customers.

As a result I would like port 80 and 443 to be open *only* on the primary server IP address. I've searched for an `iptables` command that will cover this, but I haven't found anything (only results which say how to allow/block ports for certain foreign IPs).

Is this possible with `iptables`? If so, how?

The operating system is Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

Comment: Why the -1? As far as I know I asked a good question. Gameservers or not, it's still a professional environment, or are gameserver providers not proper businesses now?

Comment: If you hover over the downvote arrow, it says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". I'd hazard a guess that the first downvote referred to the first part of that sentence; the second definitely did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can block/Allow based on IPs as well. In the man Page http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables

> -s, --source [!] address[/mask]
>       Source specification. Address can be either a network name, a hostname (please note that specifying any name to be resolved with a
>   remote query such as DNS is a really bad idea), a network IP address
>   (with /mask), or a plain IP address. The mask can be either a network
>   mask or a plain number, specifying the number of 1's at the left side
>   of the network mask. Thus, a mask of 24 is equivalent to
>   255.255.255.0. A "!" argument before the address specification inverts the sense of the address. The flag --src is an alias for this option. 
>   -d, --destination [!] address[/mask]
>       Destination specification. See the description of the -s (source) flag for a detailed description of the syntax. The flag --dst is an
>   alias for this option.

So you can do something like

`sudo iptables -A INPUT -d [serverip]/32 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`

will only allow on port 80 to the specified IP or you can block listening on the other ip's

For source address the flag is `-s`